# Is the outer automorphism group of a finite poset finite when the Coxeter matrix has finite order?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, posets

Let $P$ be a finite connected poset.
The Cartan matrix $C_P$ of $P$ is defined as the matrix with entries $c_{i,j}=1$ if $i \leq j$ and $c_{i,j}=0$ else for $i,j \in P$.
The Coxeter matrix of $P$ is defined as $M_P\mathrel{:=}-C_P^{-1}C_P^T$. The order of a matrix $M$ is defined as the smallest $k$ such that $M^k=\operatorname{id}$.

> Question: When the Coxeter matrix $M_P$ of a poset has finite order, does it follow that the incidence algebra $A_P$ of $P$ has finite outer automorphism group (over any field)?

This is true for all posets with at most 7 points.

Comment: Over an infinite field, the outer automorphism group is finite if and only if the mod 2 cycle subspace (or circuit subspace) of the Hasse diagram of $P$ is generated by cycles consisting of two saturated chains with the same endpoints. Does this property follow from the finite order of $M_P$?